# Angular2 file upload component that returns data

Tags: angular

I want to create a file upload component that reads the file, parse it and returns the Object.
This is my main component.

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Parameter } from './parameter.interface';
import { FlexUpload } from './flexUpload.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-flexUpload></app-flexUpload>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  fUp : FlexUpload = new FlexUpload();

  ngOnInit(){
    this.fUp.getData().then(data => console.log(data));
  }
  
}
```

The data received from fUp.getData should be used.

This is my FlexUpload component

```js
import { Component,ElementRef, Input, ViewChild,Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flexUpload',
  templateUrl : './flexUpload.component.html',
})

@Injectable()
export class FlexUpload{

  @ViewChild('fileInput') inputEl: ElementRef;


  changed(){
    let res: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    let myFile = res.files[0];

    var data;

    data = io.readZipFile([myFile]);
    console.log(data); //--> this works, want to return it in getData()
    

  };

  getData():Promise<any>{
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=> resolve(4),5000);// instead of 4, I want to return data when it is  parsed
    });
  }

}
```

Till now getData() only returns 4 after waiting 5 seconds, I would like to return data, when a file was uploaded and the data was parsed.
How can I do this?
Can I somehow observe data?

Best and Thanks in advance,
P

Comment: I don't see the point of that filereader thing if you pass `myFile` to `io.readZipFile`...

Comment: io.readZipFile is a javascript function that unzip the file, extract the information and save it in an object.

Comment: yes but I guess it does that asynchronously, because it will need to read the file with a file reader so I don't understand why you read it before you send it to that function...

Comment: Hi, you are right, I don't need it. Will change it.

Comment: so I guess io.readZipFile returns a `Promise`, right ?

Comment: Hi, It returns an array with objects.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't aware of the @Output.
I could solve it after watching this video:
https://youtu.be/xFYzfHGCJBw.

This is my new AppComponent

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-flexUpload (onYell)="yell($event)"></app-flexUpload>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  
yell(data:any){
  console.log(data);//data comes out here
}

}
```

It waits for the onYell event and then calls the yell($event) function.
The onYell event is transmitted after a file was selected and read in FlexUpload's changed() function

```js
declare var io:any;

import { Component,ElementRef, Input, ViewChild,Injectable,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flexUpload',
  template: `<input type="file" [multiple]="multiple" #fileInput (change)="changed()" >`,
})

@Injectable()
export class FlexUpload{

  @ViewChild('fileInput') inputEl: ElementRef;
  @Output() onYell = new EventEmitter(); 

  changed(){// is called when a file is selected
    let res: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    let myFile = res.files[0];

    var data;

    data = io.readZipFile([myFile]);//uses HTML5 file api
    this.onYell.emit(data);// emit data
  };


}
```